# PC/SC & NFC Proximity Provider conflict?

Tags: windows, nfc, proximity, pcsc

I am trying to develop an App to get Mifare card UID (CSN) with the PC/SC library to be used on a Dell notebook that has the contactless reader.  My code works on some laptop, but it doesn't work on a laptop that has the NFC Proximity Provider driver displayed in the Device Manager.

[image]

I have tested the ProximityDevice code on the laptop that have the NFC Proximity Provider and it received the events as expected but I cannot get the card UID.  It seems that all the cards scan are routed to the NFC app and not the PC/SC app.

Is there a setting to be made on the laptop for the PC/SC code to work?

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line tool in the dell driver called "setcardsrouting.exe"

download and extract 
Dell-ControlVault2-Driver-and-Firmware_W53NH_WIN64_4.6.31.67_A10

setcardsrouting -t4rfid
setcardsrouting -t3rfid

iThis will change the routing of most kinds of cards from NFC to RFID

That said, It will not let me change the routing for the Mifare ultralight (ISO1443-3A)cards :(